# Adding an array in an existing key in an associative array PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

Title sounds a bit convoluted but the title itself is pretty self-descriptive I think.

Assume that I have an associative array like this:

```
$data['blog_info'] = array(
   "title" => "Adventure",
   "author" => "Yo"
);
```

Now, I would like add to the current key 'blog_info" another set of key => value array. so the result should be :

```
$data['blog_info'] = array(
   "title" => "Adventure",
   "author" => "Yo",
   "ISBN" => "23423498"
);
```

so for example I would like to add "ISBN" => "23423498" inside this 'blog_info' key. How am I able to achieve this? (but by going like $data['blog_info'].push("ISBN" => "23423498") etc?)

Comment: You want something like `$data['blog_info']['ISBN']`?

Comment: What would the result look like? Also, the `{..}` are incorrect.

Comment: In PHP `array_push` or the `[]` operator would allow you to push an item to an array but since you have an associative array (Strings as keys) you should use `$data['blog_info']['ISBN'] = '23423498';` to achieve your desired result. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The below will achieve it (`$data['blog_info']` is just an array).

```
$data['blog_info']['ISBN'] = '23423498';
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you don't need the curly braces `{` and `}` in this context.

```
$data['blog_info'] = array(
   "title" => "Adventure",
   "author" => "Yo"
);
```

Try something like

```
$data['blog_info']['ISBN'] = '23423498';
```